# UIView bottom not showing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm doing a navigation based app. My rootview is a UITableView and from that I'm navigation to a UIView. For some reason the height of the UIView seems bigger than it should, meaning that the bottom of the view is not showing.

I did a really simple test using a UITextView with a button at the bottom, and only the top half of the button shows in the view when i run it in Simulator even though the height is set to 460.

Here's the code I use to navigate:

```
TestViewController *t = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:t animated:YES];
```

In my test the .xib is just made in IB dragging a textview and a button to the UIView.

I don't have the same issue when I'm navigating to another UITableView.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is really not enough info in your question to answer it.

Comment: I realize that the amount of info is scarce, however, there really isn't much more to it. I've broken it down to a bare minimum of code to try to pinpoint the issue, but no luck. Please inform me what other information you would need to help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have those in the IB

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

which means that the viewControllers' view gets resized by the navigationController, the textView gets resized by the main view and the distance from the top stays the same as in your nib, and finally the distance from the bottom of the view stays the same for your button.

If you don't know how to translate these values in your IB UI, arrows is resizing and "I" is fixed distance to that side - left, top, right, bottom.

The height of the view in a navigation based app should be 480 - statusbarHeight (=20) - navigationBarHeight (=44) = 416 pixels

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess there's no need for me to point out my noob status, so suffice it to say that 416 did the trick.

Comment: Just make sure you learn this auto-layout/size matters before you go into more complex views, it's going to save a lot of your time trying to pinpoint what setting ruins your layout :). Nice name btw snooker fun?

Comment: And concerning the auto-resizing stuff, I've been looking into it a lot. Super important concept to understand. Can mess everything up :)